# React POST requests with Express/Node and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, crud

I'm writing program that uses React as front-end, and an Express/Node API for the backend which then does CRUD operations in a MongoDB database. Right now, I'm using the native JS fetch() API to perform GET/POST operations on my front end. The GET requests work just fine, but my POST requests seem to not be working. On my front end, I have a form and a handler for form submission like so:

```
handleSubmit(){
    let databody = {
        "name": this.state.nameIn,
        "quote": this.state.quoteIn
    }

    return fetch('http://localhost:5002/stored', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(databody),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data)); 
}


render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Name
                    <input type="text" name="name" value={this.nameIn} onChange={this.handleNameChange}/>
                </label>
                <label>
                    quote
                    <input type="text" name="quote" value={this.quoteIn} onChange={this.handleQuoteChange}/>
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Add to DB" />
            </form> 
        </div>
    );
}
```

Then on my Express API, which is on port 5002, I have:

```
app.post('/stored', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    db.collection('quotes').insertOne(req.body, (err, data) => {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        res.send(('saved to db: ' + data));
    })
});
```

However, when the form is submitted, the request shows up on the Express API with an empty body. The console.log shows that req.body is just an { } I'm wondering what I did wrong?

Comment: Please check network tab of dev console. Are those objects appearing in your body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `body-parser`

in your express code add :

```
global.bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
  limit: '50mb',
  parameterLimit: 100000
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit: '50mb',
  parameterLimit: 100000
}))


app.post('/stored', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    db.collection('quotes').insertOne(req.body, (err, data) => {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        res.send(('saved to db: ' + data));
    })
});
```

in your froontend :

```
handleSubmit:function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    let databody = {
        "name": this.state.nameIn,
        "quote": this.state.quoteIn
    }

    fetch('http://localhost:5002/stored', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(databody),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use express 4.16 or later you can just use [express.json()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json), it will attempt to parse the JSON of the request body and save it to req.body, but only if the header "Content-Type: application/json" is sent along with the request:

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.json()); // Parses request body if type is json. Saves to req.body.
```